npx turbo run build failed with "npm run format-lint exited (1)"
For some integration to an existing application I need to run
npx turbo run build
After I did just a simple modification as adding a file to the source. (here all is fine, no errors are displayed in VSCode), I got the following eror:
@eclipse-sirius/sirius-components-forms:format-lint: npm ERR! Lifecycle script format-lint failed with error:
@eclipse-sirius/sirius-components-forms:format-lint: npm ERR! Error: command failed
@eclipse-sirius/sirius-components-forms:format-lint: npm ERR!   in workspace: @eclipse-sirius/sirius-components-forms@2024.3.1
@eclipse-sirius/sirius-components-forms:format-lint: npm ERR!   at location: C:\Users\CM268869\DeepLab\sirius-web\packages\forms\frontend\sirius-components-forms
@eclipse-sirius/sirius-components-forms:format-lint: ERROR: command finished with error: command (packages\forms\frontend\sirius-components-forms) npm run format-lint exited (1)
Does anybody an Idea why? And does someone have any hints for me.
Many thanks in advance.

It looks like a formatting issue. You can try to format your code by navigating to sirius-components-forms and running npm run format.
I also suggest to double check the following things to avoid this issue in the future:

Make sure you have the prettier plugin installed in VSCode
Make sure the Editor: Format On Save setting is enabled in VSCode

